# SVG linear gradient fill with opacity gradient

Tags: svg, opacity, fill

I've been reading the SVG specification and trying to find out whether you can have a combined fill and opacity gradient, but with the fill and opacity at different angles?

See the following example:

```
<linearGradient id="MyFill" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox">
    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#FF0000" />
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#0000FF" />
</linearGradient>

<linearGradient id="MyTransparency" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox">
    <stop offset="0%" stop-opacity="0%" x1="50%" x2="50%" />
    <stop offset="100%" stop-opacity="100%" x1="50%" x2="50%" />
</linearGradient>
```

The opacity is defined at a different angle to the fill, how can I combine these into one fill? Or if I can't, how can I apply this to a single object?

Comment: x1 and x2 on stop elements is not valid according to the svg spec, that will have no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not supported in SVG 1.1, but you can probably do a workaround with e.g filter markup to combine the gradients ([an example](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/filters/three-way-colored-triangle.svg)), or `<use>` to apply different gradients to the same element that way, or write a script to do the color interpolation yourself.