# Set SVG opacity as function of x and y

Tags: svg, opacity

Is it possible to set the opacity of an SVG element based on the x and y coordinates, using a continuous mathematical function? [Here, I have a 20% opacity blue rectangle](http://jsbin.com/eyojeq/1/edit), but instead of making it 20% opaque, I want to define the rectangle's opacity at each point using the function `sin(x)/2+sin(y)/2`, where x and y are the coordinates of each point inside the rectangle.

```
<svg>
  <rect width="100" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:1;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" fill-opacity="0.2" />
</svg>
```

I've tried setting the opacity to `"Math.sin(x)/2+Math.sin(y)/2"`, but this doesn't produce the desired effect. How can I set the opacity of an SVG polygon as a function of the x and y coordinates?

Comment: This is relatively trivial to implement in javascript, have you tried anything?

Comment: this would be much better done in Canvas

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7725186/svg-linear-gradient-fill-with-opacity-gradient

Comment: @gongzhitaao That question doesn't discuss the use of continuous functions to define custom gradients, so it doesn't appear relevant to my question.

Comment: Sorry, 'cause according to definition of [fill-opacity](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#FillOpacityProperty), i dont think it's possible.  Gradient might be the most closest thing i could think of.

Comment: @Duopixel Yes, I've tried fill-opacity="Math.sin(x)/2+Math.sin(y)/2", and it doesn't seem to work at all. How would it be possible to implement this in JavaScript?

Comment: @Duopixel I don't think it would be trivial to implement: I'd need to set the color of every single pixel inside a given SVG element. Do you know of any better way to set transparency of an SVG element per-pixel?

Comment: @AndersonGreen yes, if it's "per pixel" then it's not a simple problem. I'm not sure what the end result would look like, but if your background is solid perhaps you could overlay a gradient so it seems that the elements have opacity but the gradient is actually masking the elements.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot declaratively set this in SVG. Even a user agent that supported both SVG and CSS3's [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/calc) function would not be able to do this, since the only valid operands are CSS length units, not arbitrary properties.

To do this you would need to either:

1. Dynamically generate the SVG with the opacity being based off of knowledge of the object's being built, or
2. Generate the document without this information and then process it to add them.

Implementations for #2 could be via XSLT (or any other 'one-off' conversion technology that creates a new document) or in-memory via UA scripting (e.g. JavaScript).

A JavaScript solution might look something like this:

```js
var rects = document.querySelectorAll('rect');
for (var i=rects.length;i--;){
  // Assumes that all rects are neither transformed, nor are they
  // inside any transformation hierarchy
  var rect = rects[i];
  var x = (rect.getAttribute('x')||0)*1;
  var y = (rect.getAttribute('y')||0)*1;
  var opacity = Math.sin(x)/2+Math.sin(y)/2;
  rect.setAttribute('opacity',opacity);
}
```

**Edit**: Note that this will affect the opacity of the shape singularly. If instead you are asking to control the opacity of the shape per pixel, as a fill effect, my answer is: No, I'm pretty sure (but not positive) that there is no way to do this with [SVG Filter Effects](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/filters.html#feComponentTransferElement).

The closest you could get would be to use two `<feComponentTransfer>` with [`<feFuncA type="table">`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-SVG11-20030114/filters.html#feFuncAElement) mapping X and Y linear gradients to the function of your choice, and then combining those values later.

Comment: Actually, I'm trying to control the opacity per pixel.

Comment: Then see the Edit at the bottom. No, you can't do this in general. Depending on the equation, you might be able to make a filter that implemented it by pre-computing lookup tables for the functions involved.

Comment: I suppose I could try to subdivide a polygon into 1x1 pixel rectangles, each with different opacities. That would at least provide a good approximation. (Then, of course, I'd need to find a way to check whether or not each pixel was inside the polygon).